# Editing functions with psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

When using `\ef <function_name>` to edit a function with `psql`, it puts the modified function (which can be over 100 lines in some cases) into the query buffer to execute.  Works great!  But, then when I up-arrow to scroll through history, the whole function pops back up, and in a couple of cases is longer than the terminal window and it's kind of mess.  Is there anyway to keep the actual "create or replace function" out of history?

Just an annoyance here, but it really bugs me, and I'm obviously either the only one or I can't figure out the right Google search for how to fix. :\

note: I do understand that I can go into the `.psql_history` file and manually remove the entries.  It would just be nice to not have to do this.

Comment: I doubt it's possible from within Postgres directly. If it was, it would defeat the purpose of logging the history to begin with.

Comment: I would really like to know why there are 2 "close" votes.  WTF!?  The meets the criteria to post on this board. It's a question related to "software tools commonly used by programmers" and is "practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development". Note: the answer might be 'NO', but that's still and answer.  So, what else does it need to be?  I'm sure not fishing for rep points. It's not an opinion-based question.  And believe me, I google'd on multiple occasions trying to find a solution. I hate to post on SO, it's my always my last option (because of issues like this).

Comment: Speaking for myself, I voted to close the question on grounds that, as much as it's a valid question (it didn't get down voted, as you can see), but it belongs on Superuser (or DBA). I'm pretty sure the other close vote was for similar reasons.

Comment: @Denis I thought about posting it on DBAs, but the traffic is much less on that board, and software developers often use this tool, so it meets the criteria.  At the very least, the question should have gotten the benefit of the doubt. If you really wanted to be helpful, you might have included moving it as a suggestion in your comment. Instead you seem to have just wanted to show your disdane for the question.

Comment: Huh? What disdain? Where? Chill out, dude. I commented that no, probably not. It's for the same reason you can't filter anything out of a root user's history file: the whole point of logging is to leave an audit trail. And sure enough, a PG core dev chimed in to confirm. You then ask why the close votes, and I politely answered: it simply belongs on SU. If it gets close for that reason, it'll get migrated automatically.

Comment: @Denis.  My apologies. I think I took out some unwarranted SO-related frustrations on you.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not possibility to filter history in psql - and what I know, there is no plan to change it.

Sorry for offtopic - write only adhoc function in psql. Don't use psql or pgAdmin for writing plpgsql functions. These tools has this functionality, and it is not bad, but much more preferable way is writing to file (mainly for nontrivial functions) - use your favourite editor and import this file to Postgres.

- files can be simply versioned - use Git, ...
- code in files can be logically modularized
- code in files can be much richer commented
- use "make", "Makefile" for import
- with git or other similar tool - code can be simply shared in team - anybody can know who and what did in code.